# Why would the VS2010 Debugger Hang?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

This just started happening on both my work box and home.

In Visual Studio 2010, I'll start a debugging session and the program will run to the first breakpoint and that's it.

I can hit F10/11/5 all I want. Nothing will happen. The only way to get out is a Shift+F5.

This driving me nuts!

Both machines are 64 bit Windows 7. Though, that's where the similarities end.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Why did you make this a Community Wiki?  It's a valid question

Comment: Any wininet related code?  Disable the symbol server temporarily.

Comment: the XSLT debugger still loves to do this :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my experience the most common reason for Visual Studio hanging is a property is being auto-evaluated and gets stuck in native code causing a hang.  The first step I would take would be to disable auto-evaluated properties and implicit function calls in the debugger.

- Tools -> Options
- Go to Debugger
- Uncheck "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls"