# InvalidOperationException in my Lazy<> value factory

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, lazy-evaluation

I have a class containing something like the following:

```
public static class Config
{
    private static Lazy<ConfigSource> _cfgSrc = new Lazy<ConfigSource>(
        () => { /* "ValueFactory" here... */ },
        true);

    public static ConfigSource ConfigSource
    {
        get { return _cfgSrc.Value; }
    }
}
```

In accessing the `ConfigSource` property, I encountered this `InvalidOperationException`:

> ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.

I don't see anything in my "value factory" method that accesses the `Value` property.  Is there anything else that could be triggering this exception?  This problem only happens intermittently, but once it does, it takes resetting IIS to clear up the Exception (which appears to be cached once it occurs).

Comment: Can you post the code in `/* "ValueFactory" here... */`, or at least some code that makes it crash? The problem might be there.

Comment: Multithreaded execution per chance?

Comment: @Gleno, wouldn't the `true` argument ensure that locks will be used to prevent instantiation on multiple threads?

Comment: @sixlettervariables, you should post that as an answer.  The cached exception that gets thrown doesn't have an inner stacktrace pointing to the problem, but maybe the first time it is thrown it does.

Comment: @Alxandr, the factory code is too complex to post; after doing manual static analysis, I don't think the factory references the Lazy object; maybe the stacktrace (if I can get one) will help.

Comment: @Gleno, there's an overload that takes a Boolean, which basically translates `true` to `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`

Comment: @Jacob, yes, you are right. I forgot that the constuctor was overloaded, there's another to specify the exact type of locking that takes a LazyThreadSafetyMode object.

Comment: This issue was happening to me with almost the exact same code as you have above. After reading this post I realized I had a recursive call to "ConfigSource" inside the section you have labeled /* "ValueFactory" here... */.  That may not be your issue but it worth a double check.

Comment: I had the issue in unit tests with AutoMapper, but latest AutoMapper v8.0 fixed the problem https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1847

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It turned out that this error only occurred when trying to inspect the `Value` property of the `Lazy<>` in the Visual Studio debugger.  Doing so appeared to create a deadlock because the accessing of `Value` then seemed to hang the thread for a long time until the `InvalidOperationException` finally occurred.  I could never intercept the original `Exception`, so I couldn't see the inner stacktrace.

I'm just chalking this up as a bug in Visual Studio or their implementation of `Lazy<>`.

Comment: +1 I agree with your thoughts that there is a bug in the implementation of `Lazy<T>` I encountered this same issue today and there are no exceptions raised in my code. To solve my issues I switched to using a property with a `get { return _val ?? (_val = CreateVal()); }` .

Comment: Visual Studio was consistently hanging (indefinitely?) when I tried to step through code in a web-app.  On detaching from the process I got this error thrown back to the browser.  Unchecking "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536025/why-would-the-vs2010-debugger-hang seems to have sorted it.

Comment: I found in my solutions that the issue was caused by a bug in the DefaultRegistry, and that following the stack trace led me towards the issue.

Answer (score 20):

This has also happened to me with circular dependencies, so if these steps lead you nowhere, try double checking the stacktrace and verifying that there are no circular dependencies.

Comment: yes, I defined two Lazy properties in terms of each other, and I got this weird exception

Answer (score 16):

> ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.

It may help somebody, I was able to fix that error by inspecting my entire ValueFactory procedure.
In my example, I was creating a simple model and the linked it with some other data but during the linking process I was accessing the Value property in a singleton and that caused the error.

So **accessing the Value of a Lazy object inside the ValueFactory throws** such **an error**.
As the error message is already indicating ;-)

Comment: Make sure that watch, locals or autos window is not open. It might try to access Value when breakpoint inside ValueFactory is hit.

Answer (score 8):

[The behavior of `Lazy<T>` is to cache exceptions thrown by the `ValueFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx). This can lead to potentially confusing behavior due to the paucity of information given in the `InvalidOperationException` message. [Microsoft was made aware of this issue through Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/508115/lazy-t-invalidoperationexception-message-not-explicit), however, it is marked as *Wont Fix* as they feel there is enough information in the exception itself to diagnose the problem.

If there is an inner exception for the IOE you receive, it should (not saying it will) contain enough information to continue onwards. Another possibility is you have a `try...catch` blocks which rethrows exceptions (`throw ex;` instead of `throw;`), you will lose valuable information.

Answer (score 8):

To make sure your exception isn't cached, use LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly as a second parameter, instead of true.

Using true, you'll end up with a LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication. This will ensure only one thread enteres the ValueFactory method, but also ensures exceptions will be cached.

```
  private static Lazy<ConfigSource> _cfgSrc = new Lazy<ConfigSource>(
        () => { /* "ValueFactory" here... */ },
        LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);
```

See the link sixlettervariables provided for more information.

Comment: I don't like that `PublicationOnly` still allows the initialization code to run in multiple threads (even if those extra results are discarded), but that is nice that exceptions aren't cached.

Comment: `PublicationOnly` also allows recursive access to the `Value` property of the `Lazy<T>` instance without throwing an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: @Jacob:Have you got the solutions regarding "I don't like that PublicationOnly still allows the initialization code to run in multiple threads (even if those extra results are discarded), but that is nice that exceptions aren't cached", I am also looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When lazy loading a configuration, be sure to not call methods that need said configuration. This will recall the configuration loader which starts over the process, resulting in the described error.

In my case, I was logging the loadstate, while the logger required a configuration

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed caused by nested `Lazy` instances when one calls another `Value` in the factory but more specifically it is caused by different publication modes of these `Lazy` instances e.g. one is `PublicationOnly` and other is `None`. I think it is actually a bug in Lazy implementation.

```
[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
    var innerLazy = new Lazy<string>(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        return "lazy";
    }, LazyThreadSafetyMode.None);
    var outerLazy = new Lazy<string>(() => innerLazy.Value, LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);

    var task1 = new Task<string>(() => outerLazy.Value);
    task1.Start();
    var task2 = new Task<string>(() => outerLazy.Value);
    task2.Start();

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

    Assert.That(outerLazy.Value, Is.EqualTo("lazy"));
}
```