# lazy<T> with LazyThreadSafetyMode.None can throw NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, lazy-evaluation

I defined the following `Lazy<Y>`:

```
var preinitializedValue = new X();

this.lazy = new Lazy<X>(() => preinitializedValue, LazyThreadSafetyMode.None);
```

Later on the `Lazy<T>.Value` is accessed from multiple threads. After starting the application, at random times the `Value` fails to initialize and breaks for the remainder of the AppDomain. Only a restart solves the problem. The following exception is thrown:

> ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.

This exception seems to be a cached as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300398/invalidoperationexception-in-my-lazy-value-factory).

After investigating, the root problem seems to be that the originating error is a `NullReferenceException`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   (NullReferenceException)

What is going on here? Why does the `Lazy<T>` throw a `NullReferenceException` at random times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this sometimes fails is because `LazyThreadSafetyMode.None` doesn't give any guarantees about correctness when accessed over multiple threads. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `LazyThreadSafetyMode.None` states:

> The Lazy instance is not thread safe; if the instance is accessed
>   from multiple threads, its behavior is undefined. Use this mode only
>   when high performance is crucial and the Lazy instance is
>   guaranteed never to be initialized from more than one thread.

You incorrectly assumed that since your delegate always returned the same value, no thread-safety was needed, but this isn't the case.

You should initialize the `Lazy<T>` with either `PublicationOnly` or `ExecutionAndPublication`.